# How to load datatable on change of dropdown

Tags: laravel-5

I have a view where there is a dropdown and datatable.
At initial load, I am loading the values to be loaded in the datatable based on the first select of dropdown and on change of dropdown, I want to fetch data based on that condition and populate those data on the datatable.

Please anyone suggest a way to do this!

I am trying a way using get request but it is reloading the page and hence I am unable to make the data persist in the datatable.

I followed exactly this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/filtering-data-using-drop-down-onchange-event

Data is coming and populates to the datatable but just after a second, it reloads and comes to old data in datatable.

Please either correct my or suggest some new way to do it!

Comment: check what parameters are passing through your ajax function on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, I found that in one of the js file included, there were a code

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {  
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Since, this code was making it to reload on every ajax call completes, I faced this issue.